# In Python, how to create all possible combinations of inter-linked lists?

Tags: python, list

I have always had this crazy and possibly counterintuitive idea before all my "home exams" that I can create a list of all possible combinations of all the formulas. By doing this I might be able to enter some basic values into different variables that I have from a test and get a list of formulas that fit the problem. Basic example:

Ohms law

```
U = R * I
```

Jouls law

```
P = U * I
```

but these two lists can be combined:

```
P = R * I * I
```

or

```
I = U / R
```

which implies

```
P = U * U / R
```

How would one go about creating all the possible combinations of these lists? At first I though about creating different lists such as

```
ohms_law = ['R', 'U', 'I']
jouls_law = ['P', 'U', 'I']
.
.
.
```

however, these is the issue of actually connecting them as well as the issue of where to put the actual equal sign, division sign, etc.

Can anybody help me come closer to finishing this incredibly inefficient and useless idea? Just for fun.

Edit: For those with lower level of education that have never used formulas.

```
Formula 1: U = R * I
Formula 2: P = U * I

Output:
U = R * I
P = U * I
P = U * U / R
P = I * I * R
R = U / I
I = U / R
U = P / I
.
.
.
cont.
```

what I am doing here is just matching the formulas with each other. The first formula says that U is equal to I times R. This means that we can insert that into the second formula to get a new formula. I want all of these combinations.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Could you provide some sample outputs? I think that will make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @Inogueir I have provided examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal. The end-result is wrong, I did not want to spend too much time fixing bugs, but you can see how I tried to solve the problem.

```py
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Unit:  # as in Physical Quantity
    name: str


R = Unit("R")
U = Unit("U")
I = Unit("I")
P = Unit("P")
units = [R, U, I, P]


@dataclass
class Factor:
    unit: Unit
    dimension: int  # should not be zero

    def pretty(self) -> str:
        operand_sign = "*" if self.dimension > 0 else "/"
        return f"{operand_sign} {operand_sign.join(' ' + self.unit.name + ' ' for _ in range(abs(self.dimension)))}"


@dataclass
class Formula:  # only considering its quantities
    result: Unit
    factors: typing.List[Factor]

    def pretty(self) -> str:
        # TODO: this formatting is ugly, it produces "R = /  I  *  U " for example
        return f"{self.result.name} = " + " ".join(factor.pretty() for factor in self.factors)


ohms_law = Formula(U, [Factor(R, 1), Factor(I, 1)])
jouls_law = Formula(P, [Factor(U, 1), Factor(I, 1)])


# now we have to rewrite each formula in each combination of its factors/result
def reformulate(formula: Formula, unit: Unit) -> Formula:
    # FIXME: I am sure this function is incorrect, notably if unit is not of dimension -1 in the base formula
    assert unit in (_factor.unit for _factor in formula.factors)
    new_formula = Formula(
            result=unit,
            factors=[
                Factor(_factor.unit, dimension=-_factor.dimension)
                for _factor in formula.factors if _factor.unit != unit
            ] + [
                Factor(formula.result, dimension=1)
            ]
        )
    return new_formula


base_formulas = [ohms_law, jouls_law]
print("base formulas:")
for base_formula in base_formulas:
    print(base_formula.pretty())

formulas = base_formulas + [
    reformulate(base_formula, factor.unit)
    for base_formula in base_formulas
    for factor in base_formula.factors
]
print("base reformulations:")
for formula in formulas:
    print(formula.pretty())


# it will be handy to know, for each quantity, which formula can produce it
formulas_by_unit: typing.Dict[str, typing.List[Formula]] = {
    unit.name: # NOTE: we have to hash by `unit.name` because a Unit is not simply hashable, but a string is
        [formula for formula in formulas
         if (unit == formula.result)]
    for unit in units
}
print("possible formulas for substitution:")
print("\n".join(unit_name + ": " + str([formula.pretty() for formula in formulas])
                for unit_name, formulas in formulas_by_unit.items()))


# now that we have set the data and its structure, we can create new formulas

def substitute(formula1: Formula, common_unit: Unit, formula2: Formula) -> Formula:
    """Replace the common_unit from formula1 with its definition from formula2."""
    return Formula(
        result=formula1.result,
        factors=merge_factors(
            # FIXME: take into account that the factor from formula1 may have a dimension != 1
            [factor for factor in formula1.factors if factor.unit != common_unit],
            formula2.factors
        )

    )


def merge_factors(factors1: typing.List[Factor], factors2: typing.List[Factor]) -> typing.List[Factor]:
    """Merge the two lists of factors, combining those of the same unit by adding their dimension."""
    factors1_by_unit = {factor.unit.name: factor for factor in factors1}
    factors2_by_unit = {factor.unit.name: factor for factor in factors2}
    units_only_in_factors1 = set(factors1_by_unit.keys()).difference(factors2_by_unit)
    units_only_in_factors2 = set(factors2_by_unit.keys()).difference(factors1_by_unit)
    units_in_both = set(factors1_by_unit.keys()).intersection(factors2_by_unit)
    return [
        *(factors1_by_unit[unit_name] for unit_name in units_only_in_factors1),
        *(factors2_by_unit[unit_name] for unit_name in units_only_in_factors2),
        *(
            Factor(unit=Unit(unit_name), dimension=factor1.dimension + factor2.dimension)
            for unit_name in units_in_both
            for factor1 in (factors1_by_unit[unit_name],)
            for factor2 in (factors2_by_unit[unit_name],)
            if factor1.dimension + factor2.dimension != 0
        )
    ]


print("reformulations:")
for base_unit in units:
    for base_formula in formulas_by_unit[base_unit.name]:
        # find possible substitutions
        for substituable_factor in base_formula.factors:
            for candidate_substitution_formula in formulas_by_unit[substituable_factor.unit.name]:
                if base_unit not in (factor.unit for factor in candidate_substitution_formula.factors):
                    reformulation = substitute(base_formula, substituable_factor.unit, candidate_substitution_formula)
                    print(reformulation.pretty())
```

```
base formulas:
U = *  R  *  I 
P = *  U  *  I 
base reformulations:
U = *  R  *  I 
P = *  U  *  I 
R = /  I  *  U 
I = /  R  *  U 
U = /  I  *  P 
I = /  U  *  P 
possible formulas for substitution:
R: ['R = /  I  *  U ']
U: ['U = *  R  *  I ', 'U = /  I  *  P ']
I: ['I = /  R  *  U ', 'I = /  U  *  P ']
P: ['P = *  U  *  I ']
reformulations:
R = *  P 
R = *  P  /  I / I 
P = *  R  *  I * I 
P = /  R  *  U * U
```

For example, the first result is `R = *  P`  which is **wrong** !
It tries to reformulate `'R = /  I  *  U '` with `'I = /  U  *  P '`. But the I has dimension -1, which is not taken into account. So it sees two `U`, one of dimension 1, one of dimension -1, and cancels them out.

Apart from the bugs, you should be able to understand how I proceeded.